# Creating thumbnails from a swf file in php?

Tags: php, flash, thumbnails

I'm looking for a script that will generate jpg thumbnails on the fly (in php) from a swf file. Does anyone know where I can find something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead chek out the Flash Bitmap class~ a bunch of amazing stuff can be done with it~~!!!
Check out the examples and sources here by Andrew Trice of Cynergy (the last few ones)

http://www.cynergysystems.com/blogs/page/andrewtrice?entry=flex_2_bitmapdata_tricks_and

The main idea is to get the bitmap data and send to PHP GD library to create the images.

another option look at :

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

i take it from link : 
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Photos_Graphics/Web_Graphics/Macromedia_Flash/Q_22400739.html

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at those :)