# how to generate screenshot/thumbnail (take photo) on swf files

Tags: php, flash, thumbnails

I'm writing arcade game script. i want to take a photo for thumbnail on swf files.

have php got function for this?
Or How difficult?

1. Upload a swf file
2. Take a photo uploaded file
3. Move directory
4. Add to mysql

Comment: you want to have a screenshot of the flash application ?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding yes i want screenshot..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating thumbnails from a swf file in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130574/creating-thumbnails-from-a-swf-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with PHP alone. The best solution in my eyes is to use a browser screenshot tool on a page that embeds the flash.

Comment: PHP cant make screenshots... maybe its another flash application... but it would go for a "normal" application in java or so to do the job...

Comment: what is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php and http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/video/1/package/4608.html this?

Comment: They all use external tools - the phpclasses thingy uses internet explorer, while the SO question suggests using `wkhtmltopdf`.